# Android Custom Toolbar v7 (Look like Inbox)

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I would like to custom Toolbar like this.

What should I do?

I am using Android Toolbar (V7)

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:layout_weight="0.82"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/tripStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/nav_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/tripEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/nav_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: ActivityCompat and so on? Also you could make your question a bit clearer. Describe the wanted behavior better, show only the relevant part, Explain why there is the layout xml and what it does...

Answer (score 2):

Using palette will help but i fear you may not get the desired output, because it will just put the desired color...

i went through more examples of the sdk and i found something interesting

use Relative layout instead of linearlayout and use the tag `android:fitSystemWindows="true`".

put this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="ApplicationTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

and 
 in your toolbar just put.

```
app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
```